# How does Solo prevent space leaks?

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection, lazy-evaluation, ghc

I ran into the documentation on [`Solo`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Tuple.html#t:Solo), the one element tuple, and was a bit confused about how it says it can prevent space leaks, which makes me suspect I'm not understanding something about how the Haskell memory model and/or garbage collector works.

To quote the docs, they say:

> The most important feature of Solo is that it is possible to force its "outside" (usually by pattern matching) without forcing its "inside", because it is defined as a datatype rather than a newtype. One situation where this can be useful is when writing a function to extract a value from a data structure. Suppose you write an implementation of arrays and offer only this function to index into them:
>
> ```
> index :: Array a -> Int -> a
> ```
>
> Now imagine that someone wants to extract a value from an array and store it in a lazy-valued finite map/dictionary:
>
> ```
> insert "hello" (arr `index` 12) m
> ```
>
> This can actually lead to a space leak. The value is not actually extracted from the array until that value (now buried in a map) is forced. That means the entire array may be kept live by just that value! Often, the solution is to use a strict map, or to force the value before storing it, but for some purposes that's undesirable.

This is what I'm having trouble understanding. Presumably `a` is boxed, and hence the array `arr` is an array of pointers (if it wasn't boxed, `a` would already be evaluated and this argument would be moot).

So I'm guessing there's this pointer in this array `arr` to an unevaluated thunk that is of type `a`. We then place it in the map, so the map now contains a pointer to an unevaluated thunk of type `a`. Now I don't understand why this array `arr` needs to stay alive at this point. Nothing we've created in the map points to `arr`. The map has got it's own pointer to the unevaluated thunk of type `a`, which it can evaluate at it's own leisure. The only thing keeping `arr` alive might be if the unevaluated thunk depends on the array `arr`, but if that's the case I'm not sure how wrapping the value in a `Solo` data type helps?

I'm sure I'm missing something. And I suspect understanding what I'm missing will expose what of my above thinking is wrong. And that's a good thing if I can work out where I'm wrong. So any ideas/explanations?

Answer (score 12):

There are essentially two kinds of "space leaks" in Haskell. One is wasting space on thunks when it would have been more space efficient to just produce the value early. The other is wasting space on big data structures when it would have been more efficient to produce them later (or not at all).

The authors are considering an expression like this:

```
index arr 12
```

Imagining that `arr` is a large data structure and the result is a single element contained within it; all `index` does is select the element. If the expression `index arr 12` is left as a thunk, the thunk will necessarily contain a reference to `arr`, and thus the garbage collector will not be able to reclaim the memory of `arr` while the thunk is live.

The usual obvious thing to do would be to arrange for `index arr 12` to be executed earlier than actually required (as the authors suggest, putting it in a strict `Map` rather than a lazy one, but the context of "putting it in a map" isn't actually necessary). If you force the expression `index arr 12` when you decide that's what you're getting (as a strict map would do when you insert something into it), rather than when you actually use it for anything, then the function `index` has run to completion at that point of decision and the reference to `arr` no longer needs to be kept around until you use the result.

But remember that forcing something evaluates it to the outermost **data constructor**. `index` doesn't involve any data constructors, since it just returns a value that was already inside `arr`. So the outermost data constructor reached by evaluating `index arr 12` is going to be something from whatever type the element is. But what if the elements of `arr` (or at least the one at index 12) *were themselves stored as unevaluated thunks*? If those elements are actually large, it's entirely possible that fully generating one of those elements isn't much better than storing a big array of thunks<sup>1</sup>. By forcing `index arr 12` early we may have avoided one kind of space leak (keeping a big thunk too long) but caused another (producing a big value too early). And without pinning down the type involved, we can't know which is worse!

The problem is that evaluating to the outermost data constructor has forced "too much". We want the evaluation to proceed far enough to no longer depend on `arr` (i.e. to know which of the elements it contained we are returning), but we don't want to actually enter a thunk representing the element.

The way you could use `Solo` here is simply to wrap a data constructor *around* the returned element, so that when you force the thunk to the outermost constructor you get to `Solo` and no further. The authors state that it a common solution to the issue of space leaks from indexing thunks holding onto entire arrays is "to include an indexing function that can produce its result in an arbitrary Applicative context: `indexA :: Applicative f => Array a -> Int -> f a`", and that you could use `Solo` as the applicative to put an extra data constructor in the right place without needing to use an applicative functor that actually has any interesting effects.

As I understand it though, wrapping in `Solo` only solves the *second* potential space leak. `indexA arr 12 :: Solo a` doesn't magically stop depending on `arr` if you leave it as a thunk. However it **enables** you to use early evaluation to solve the `arr` space leak without having to accept a potential leak from the element itself.

---

<sup>1</sup> Or simply that producing it in full is costly enough, in time or space, that we don't want to pay for it *yet*. And it might not be absolutely determined that we're going to use it at all yet; if the downstream consumer turns out not to need it when we would rather not produce it *even if* the element is much smaller than the original array (all we would need is that it's smaller than the thunk representing itself).

Answer (score 6):

First off, the documentation you quoted has an error and it's actually rather relevant.

```
insert "hello" (arr index 12) m
```

should be

```
insert "hello" (index arr 12) m
```

This does, in fact, hold a pointer to `arr`. Until `index arr 12` is evaluated, it's a thunk holding pointers to each of `index`, `arr`, and `12`. The pointers to `index` and `12` aren't a big deal, but `arr` could be huge.

Now, as for the way `Solo` helps... it wouldn't, in general. That's a really weird claim. Like, they propose a function

```
indexA :: Applicative f => Array a -> Int -> f a
```

and then to use it as so:

```
case arr indexA 12 of
    Solo a -> insert "hello" a m
```

But that wouldn't actually help with anything, unless `indexA` has a really unexpected implementation. `Solo`'s implementation of `pure` is non-strict, as expected from the description of the data type. So the expected implementation of `indexA` just wraps the result of the lookup with `pure`:

```
indexA arr i = pure $ index arr i
```

In order for the explanation provided to make any sense, the implementation would need to be more like this:

```
indexA arr i = pure $! index arr i
```

I suppose if a library provides that function it only makes sense if it's got a stricter implementation, but I'm wary of assuming that's the implementation of a function like that or that `Solo` is actually useful to solve problems like this documentation proposes.

Now, there is something actually useful about the strictness properties of `Solo`, specifically with regards to the `Monad` instance. Let's contrast with the `Monad` instance of `Identity`:

```
ghci> do { x <- pure () ; y <- undefined ; pure x } :: Identity ()
Identity ()

ghci> do { x <- pure () ; y <- undefined ; pure x } :: Solo ()
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  undefined, called at <interactive>:8:26 in interactive:Ghci4
```

The fact that `Solo` is lifted where `Identity` is not makes the `Monad` instance for `Solo` more strict. `(>>=)` forces the evaluation of the outer `Solo` constructor in its first argument, which means it actually notices if it gets a bottom value as its first argument when it's otherwise unused. Because `Identity` constructors don't exist at run time, evaluating them just defers all computation for later, making the `(>>=)` implementation less strict

Answer (score 3):

> So I'm guessing there's this pointer in this array arr to an unevaluated thunk that is of type a. We then place it in the map, so the map now contains a pointer to an unevaluated thunk of type a. Now I don't understand why this array arr needs to stay alive at this point.

The point is that `insert "hello" (index arr 12) m` *doesn't* just place the existing unevaluated thunk into the map. It creates a new thunk to represent `index arr 12`, and stores *that* in the map. And that thunk does require `arr` to still be alive.